# ElasticSearch Query time - how to decrease the response time

Tags: elasticsearch, response-time

I am executing some queries on elastic search.
Some of the queries are taking long time to execute first time and on rerun response time reduces.

However, first time execution is nearing 16 secs for some of the queries.

I have increased the vCPU from 1vCPU  to 2vCPU (ElasticSearch server is running as a VM) and I can see certain decrease in the response time ("took" in elastic search).

Can someone please help and summarize, what all factors (both hardware and software e.g. query construct) affect the response time in ElasticSearch.

I am using Java to query ES.

Comment: Can you update with your cluster hardware configuration specifics?

Comment: I am using 8GB RAM with 1vCPU (2.2GHz). This is not the Prod environment.  Please let me know the minimum configuration recommended for Elastic Search.

Comment: Please let me know if any other configuration you are looking for?

Comment: those are your elasticsearch cluster configuration or your machine conf?

Comment: Those are machine conf on which elasticsearch is running. All the other settings are default excep I have set the ES_HEAP_SIZE to 4g. Is there anything else you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

First query will make a full search, next one can use some cache, that's why they are quicker.
You can check in elasticsearch for indexes based on your search fields. Your data may not be indexed correctly dependending on your kind of search, this will speed up the process.

You can also limit the number of matches, if you don't care to get all results at the same time (managing yourself pagination).

Comment: Also is there any data compression going on in elasticsearch. I can see that the size on disk of the data folder decreased after some time.

Comment: My data is indexed correctly, there are nearly 10M records.

Comment: you mean you set an index of the main search fields?